# How can I get pairs of consecutive elements in Prolog?

Tags: arrays, prolog

I have to complete a problem, in which, one task is to get consecutive pairs of an array.

For example, if the array is [1, 2, 3], the result should be
X=1 Y=2 and X=2 Y=3

Until this moment my code works fine, but after that, it doesn't output 'no'. Instead, it sticks in an infinite loop. The hard part is that **I have to do this without recursion**.

My code so far is the following:

```erlang
part_of(X, Y, List):-
    length(X, 1),
    append(_, X, Part),
    length(Y, 1),
    append(Part, Y, Part2),
    append(Part2, _, List).
```

I'm not familiar with logic programming. Everything that goes through my mind have to do with returning values, which of course, is not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X` and `Y` are consecutive elements of some `List` if `List` is of the following form: some `Prefix` list, then `X`, then `Y`, then some `Rest` list.

This is kind of what you were trying to express, but you got confused on some details. First, the one-element list *containing* `X` is written as `[X]`. This is probably what you were trying to say with `length(X, 1)`, but that wouldn't work as written.

Second, you got confused with your uses of `append/3`. The way you are trying to use it, the last argument is the whole list that you are trying to decompose. So in this scenario, the third argument should always be a list that is already known -- either because it is passed in as an argument, or because it was computed by an earlier goal. In your code, the first `append/3` goal is `append(_, X, Part)`, where both `_` and `Part` are unknown. Under these circumstances there is an infinite number of solutions, which causes the nontermination you see:

```
?- append(_, X, Part).
X = Part ;
Part = [_G2897|X] ;
Part = [_G2897, _G2903|X] ;
Part = [_G2897, _G2903, _G2909|X] ;
Part = [_G2897, _G2903, _G2909, _G2915|X] ;
Part = [_G2897, _G2903, _G2909, _G2915, _G2921|X] .
```

In short, you have the right idea, but the order of binding things isn't quite right. The following works:

```
?- List = [1, 2, 3], append(Prefix, Part1, List), append([X], Part2, Part1), append([Y], Rest, Part2).
List = Part1, Part1 = [1, 2, 3],
Prefix = [],
X = 1,
Part2 = [2, 3],
Y = 2,
Rest = [3] ;
List = [1, 2, 3],
Prefix = [1],
Part1 = [2, 3],
X = 2,
Part2 = [3],
Y = 3,
Rest = [] ;
false.
```

This first splits the known list `List` = `[1, 2, 3]` into its parts, of which there are only finitely many. This binds `Part1` to a finite list. Then it splits the finite list `Part1`, binding `Part2` to a finite list, and finally it splits that. There is no room for nontermination if the initial `List` is a finite list.

All that said, there is an easier way of expressing "some list, then two adjacent elements `X` and `Y`, then some other list":

```
?- append(_Prefix, [X, Y | _Rest], [1, 2, 3]).
_Prefix = [],
X = 1,
Y = 2,
_Rest = [3] ;
_Prefix = [1],
X = 2,
Y = 3,
_Rest = [] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this:

```
pairs([X,Y|_],X,Y).
pairs([_,Y|T],A,B) :- pairs([Y|T],A,B).
```

The first predicate succeeds when it can get a pair of elements from the start of a list.

The second predicate succeeds when it can strip the first element from the list and recursively call `pairs/2` to get a subsequent pair.

Here's the output of my run:

```
?- pairs([a,b,c],X,Y).
X = a,
Y = b ;
X = b,
Y = c ;
false.
```

Comment: Looks about right, but as I mentioned, I'd like not to use recursion, since I have to solve this with two different ways and I already done the one with the recursion. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @DimitrisKaramanis - Not using recursion is kind of alien to Prolog. It's like driving a car without using the steering wheel.

Comment: the reason is to force us to learn about gathering functions such as findall.

Comment: @DimitrisKaramanis - `findall` doesn't negate the need for recursion. It just finds multiple solutions using whatever technique you're using to satisfy the goal. `length/2` and `append/3` both use recursion. I just don't know how you can do what you're asking for without it. Can you please let us know exactly what the requirements of this assignment are?

Answer (score -1):

Here is my very simple solution.

```
show_elements([X|[]],  _, _).
show_elements([X, Y|Q], A, B):- A is X, B is Y; show_elements([Y|Q], A,B).
```

Here is a photo of the output, I don't know if I correctly understood the task.

[image: Program output]

As you can see, I used recursion to solve the problem. Make sure you correctly understand recursion. It's used a lot in Prolog.

Also check the concept of unification. It is necessary to start writing programs in Prolog.

There is a lot of material online, and you can check this very useful guide: *[Lean Prolog now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/)*

Comment: I need to do this without recursions though. The output is exactly what I need but the solution is not the one I'm trying to find. I actually need both of them, but I had done the one you wrote. Thanks anyway, I will also take a look in the tutorial, I didn't know about it.

Comment: @DimitrisKaramanis ohhh okay, it would be great if you could post the assignment description

Comment: I tried running your code in SWI and got `ERROR: Arithmetic: `a/0' is not a function`.

Comment: @Ezequiel the assignment has to do with plenty of things, thus it is unnecessary. The only thing I get wrong is the function I described which does the exact same thing as your, but without recursion. It is also in Greek and I would have to translate half a page, plus I would consider it a cheating if I gave the whole assignment and I was looking for an answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity hello! that's weird, works on my. I am using SWI-Prolog(AMD64, verision 8.0.3)

Comment: @Enigmativity hey, I tried my solution with letters instead of numbers and got the arithmetic error, do you know why ?

Comment: @Ezequiel - it's because of the `is`. Change it to `=` and it works fine.